# opencv (SVM) - the parameter nu is out of range

Tags: opencv, exception, svm

The following code generates an exception saying:

> One of arguments' values is out of range- the parameter nu must be between 0 and 1

I wonder why this is happening when I've already set it to something between 0 and 1.

```
CvSVM svm;
CvParamGrid CvParamGrid_C(pow(2.0,-5), pow(2.0,15), pow(2.0,2));
CvParamGrid CvParamGrid_gamma(pow(2.0,-15), pow(2.0,3), pow(2.0,2));
CvParamGrid CvParamGrid_nu(0.4, 0.8,0.1);
const cv::Mat labelsMat(250, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);
const cv::Mat trainingDataMat(250,35, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
CvSVMParams paramz;
paramz.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;   paramz.svm_type = CvSVM::NU_SVR;
paramz.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.000001);
svm.train_auto(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), paramz, 5, 
               CvParamGrid_C, CvParamGrid_gamma, CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::P),
               CvParamGrid_nu,vSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::COEF),
               CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::DEGREE), true);
paramz = svm.get_params();
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From opencv documentation: [The grid is logarithmic, so step must always be greater then 1.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html?highlight=paramgrid#cvparamgrid)